# Build a new Drupal site using D7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm planning to rebuild a site I've got, from self-hacked to Drupal. I'm planning to dive in to Drupal and later on work as a freelancer (using Drupal).

And here's my question. After spending some time reading about, and testing, Drupal I really got that feeling, "WOW", with Drupal7! I know that D7 isn't really "out" yet but it seems that it's quite different from D6.

What I would like to ask is that if it's ok to start using D7 now or should I wait. My site is more of a personal site so not many users will do things, except for reading.

I don't really feel that I want to build my site using D6 and then haft to upgrade the whole thing later on. For example, some modules that I'm going to use is part of core in D7 bu not in D6, so I have a feeling that it's going to be a problem.

What do you think?

P.S Please have some patience with my grammar, I'm an ÅÄÖ kind of guy (Swedish) ;)

Comment: Why Drupal? Sorry for my question but why do you want to use an unreleased CMS? What Drupal can do that other systems not?

Comment: I like the way they think, the drupal way, it's called i think. And more and more agencies in Sweden is using Drupal, so it's good for a freelancer to know it.

Comment: Joomla sucks, Wordpress isn't nearly as extendable, and what else is there?

Comment: "why do you want to use an unreleased CMS". I think there are already Drupal releases (Drupal 5, Drupal 6…); Drupal 7 also has an official release, even if it is still n alpha release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a new personal site I would say go for D7. D7 is a lot more mature now than D6 was when it was launched. Many of the popular modules are in the process of being ported and there are < 40 'critical' bugs left.

Most of the more difficult bugs were in the upgade path from D6 rather than core D7 functionality.

Why not try out [Drupal Gardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com/) first. It is hosted by Aquia, which is the company owend by the guy who started Drupal, they think D7 is ok. (Eating their own dog food).

Comment: I've decided to go with D7! The backend is really a a treat and I've always been a kind of a "early adopter" so here we go... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Jump to the water !
Use Drupal, since its capabilies are really unlimited, and the community is strong and work fast.
Which version ?
I beleive it will take a while till the majority of the sites, modules, themes and developers will pass to 7. Although the move from 5 to 6 was (at least for me) suprisingly fast, I feel that nowadays Drupal as a whole is much bigger, and the move from 6 to 7 will take longer.

So, it depends what you want to achieve -

- Starting with 7 now will mean you will lead, but will mean you won't be able to use all of the existing modules, etc. It will give you a good start, but won't be very useful to your customers/users.
- Starting with 6 will mean much stronger base, but will eventually require learning 7, and maybe upgrading.

My bottom line - 6, so you will be able to start right away.
As I see it, 6 Won't disappear very fast.

Good Luck,
Shushu

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Gardens is regular Drupal 7 as SaaS and a whole lot more - See this [FAQ about what Drupal Gardens adds to Drupal 7](http://www.drupalgardens.com/faq#636n86081).  Best part is it is based on OpenSaaS which means you can export your site's database, files, and source code at any time and host it yourself if you ever outgrow Drupal Gardens.

Disclaimer: I am the VP engineering at Acquia, but don't listen to me, listen to our customers - just click the "Customer quotes" link on the footer of the Drupal Gardens site

Answer (score 0):

NO WAY!

We speaking about alpha not a release candidate

They are still critical security issue with D7.

If it's for you personal blog, why not but forget about a serious website.

Comment: "No way" and "why not" in the same thought, cool :D

Comment: lol... and things change fast now it's ok.